# Karma Unexpected Request: GET modules/home/home.html

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I just switched my application from using the Jade template engine to use client side HTML in order to improve performance and decrease server requests. Everything is working fine in the application however I'm having an issue updating my unit tests.

I have the following test:

```
describe('Registration Controller Tests', function() {
  var $controller, $scope, defer, registerSpy, doesUserExistSpy, auth, RegistrationCtrl;

  beforeEach(module('enigmaApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_, $q) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
    $scope = _$rootScope_;
    defer = $q.defer();

    // Create spies
    registerSpy = jasmine.createSpy('register').and.returnValue(defer.promise);
    doesUserExistSpy = jasmine.createSpy('doesUserExist').and.returnValue(defer.promise);

    auth = {
      register: registerSpy,
      doesUserExist: doesUserExistSpy
    };    

    // Init register controller with mocked services and scope
    RegistrationCtrl = $controller('RegistrationCtrl', {
      $scope: $scope,
      auth: auth
    });

    // digest to update controller with services and scope
    $scope.$digest();
  }));

  describe('RegistrationCtrl.register()', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
      $scope.user = {
        email: 'bwayne@wayneenterprise.com',
        first_name: 'Bruce',
        last_name: 'Wyane',
        password: 'password123'
      }
    });

    it('should call auth.register() with $scope.user', function () {
      $scope.register();
      expect(auth.register).toHaveBeenCalledWith($scope.user);
    });
});
```

Which results in the following error:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET modules/home/home.html
No more requests expected
```

Any ideas what I need to do in order to mock the routes? I've tried a few things but nothings working so far.

*Additional code:*

RegistrationCtrl

```
 .controller('RegistrationCtrl', function($scope, $state, auth) {
     $scope.user = {};
     $scope.userExists = false;
     $scope.error = '';

     $scope.register = function() {
       auth.register($scope.user)
       .then(function(response){
         $state.go('secure.user'); 
       })
       .catch(function(err){
         $scope.error = err;
       });
     };
 });
```

Comment: are you using ngMocks? It sounds like $httpBackend does not have a passthrough condition for your static html files.

Comment: Yes I'm using ngMocks, can you provide an example of the $httpBackend passthrough?

Comment: This is what I usually use: `$httpBackend.whenGET(/static\/[\w\W]*/).passThrough();` (my static files are found in the /static directory)

Comment: Thanks, add this as an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your static files are all in /modules:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/modules\/[\w\W]*/).passThrough();
```

Comment: I actually ended up with this code, but your passthrough comment got me where I needed to be: 

$httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    authReqHandler = $httpBackend.when('GET', 'modules/home/home.html').respond({ body: '<html><body>Mock homepage</body></html>'});